# Scrolling a JQuery UI Sortable in JQM

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I'm still new JQuery + JQuery UI + JQM, so please forgive me if my question is trivial,but searching the internet didn't help so far. My problem is as follows:

I'm trying to implement a mobile list editor using JQuery Mobile (JQM). I have a long list of items that fills several pages and I want to reorder items in that list. Therefore, I need to be able to drag items and scroll through the list.

In my code I'm using JQuery UI-Sortable and JQM-Listview to achieve that behavior. The issue I had at the beginning was that on mobile devices any drag gesture of a list item caused the list to scroll without moving the element. I was able to solve that issue by firing a simulatedEvent and ignoring the default handler based on the x-position of the event:

```
function touchHandler(event)
{
    var touches = event.changedTouches,
        first = touches[0],
        type = "";

    switch(event.type)
    {
        case "touchstart": type = "mousedown"; break;
        case "touchmove":  type = "mousemove"; break;        
        case "touchend":   type = "mouseup"; break;
        default: return;
    }


    var screenX = first.screenX;

    var simulatedEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    simulatedEvent.initMouseEvent(type, true, true, window, 1,
                              first.screenX, first.screenY,
                              first.clientX, first.clientY, false,
                              false, false, false, 0/*left*/, null);

    $("#list1").sortable('refreshPositions');    

    if(screenX < 100)
    {
        first.target.dispatchEvent(simulatedEvent);
        event.preventDefault();     
    }
}
```

As a result I could move elements by dragging on the left side of the screen and scroll the list by performing a scroll gesture on the right side of the screen.

In order to get persistent headers+footers and a scrollbar that indicates the current position in the list I embedded the containing  element into a JQM-Scrollview (http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/scrollview/scrollview-direction.html). However, now drag and scroll gestures are interfering again so that any drag results in a scroll. Furthermore, the scroll bar is missing although the plugin seems to work (a subtle bouncing effect can be noticed).

The whole example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/7n6Ec/3/

Any ideas how to embed the JQM-Listview containing JQuery UI-Sortables into a JQM-Scrollview so that both dragging and scrolling are possible, I get persistent header+footer and a scroll bar? (Actually something like the iPod playlist editor would be the optimal solution (http://www.tonybove.com/tonytips/figures_tips_ipod/playlist_edit2.jpg))

Thx, 
Sebastian

Comment: Sebastian, did you find a solution to this?